# Differentiating between instances of a class when debugging in Flutter / Dart

Tags: debugging, dart, flutter, instance

When debugging in Flutter or even just printing out an object as a String, there is no way that I am aware of to distinguish between different instances of an object. Looking at just line 9+ or the debugger inspection how many instances of `Foo` do `f1`, `f2` and `f3` represent?

[image]

By contrast, in Java for example each instance is printed with its address and is easy to distinguish. Even if we were debugging in some code far removed from lines 5-7 it would still be easy to tell that there are two instances present.

[image]

I could use "evaluate expression" during debugging to check for equality manually, but this does not scale well and complicates quickly if the references are in different scopes.

Is there another solution that would work better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in the console is the `toString()` method.

You can override it to print some custom informations. Most flutter widgets overrides it to print their parameters for example.

A potential override would be by adding the hashcode:

```
@override
String toString() {
  return super.toString() + " " + hashCode;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful. However what about cases where hashCode has been overwritten (eg value objects)? At runtime these objects are effectively the same, but important to distinguish at debug time.

Comment: You could obtain more information using the Observatory. https://dart-lang.github.io/observatory/